# UV Unwrap is flipped horizontally?

Tags: texturing, uv

Whenever I unwrap this plane, it seems to be unwrapped horizontally flipped.
It's a simple plane that is 'subdivided' because it's for a 3D pixel art experiment. Is there anyway to 'flip' the UV? (I know I can just flip the texture in photoshop, but there is something inherently wrong with backwards textures.)

Here's a screen capture to show what I mean.
[image: Screen Capture]

Comment: Try to flip normals and unwrap again

Comment: To flip the UVs you can select all and press S X -1

Answer (score 7):

Cegaton's comment provides the right answer but leaves out a crucial detail. First, make sure all of the vertices whose assigned textures you want to flip are selected, **then** switch to the UV editor window, and press the key sequence <kbd>S</kbd> - <kbd>X</kbd> - <kbd>1</kbd> - <kbd>-</kbd> [hyphen].

ns